# Problem retrieveing Playa child entries

Tags: playa

I'm having trouble retrieving the child pages when giving the parent id.

```
        {exp:playa:children channel="patient-services" entry_id="422"}
        <li>{title}</li>
    {/exp:playa:children}
```

This yields no results. In the CP, I have several pages with a 'Obstetrics' as the parent (which has id 422). Hopefully the attached images will show what I'm trying to do. I know this would work better in Structure, but this site wasn't planned well.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here are some ideas:**

- Add the `field=""` or `field_id=""` parameters.
- Do the children entries have a custom status set? If yes, you'll need to specify it with `status=""` parameter.
- Check the entry dates for the child entries. Is the entry date in the future? Is an expiration date set that is causing the entries not to show?
- Try removing the `channel=""` parameter and leave the `entry_id="422"`.
- Confirm `channel="patient-services"` is correct.

Comment: No custom status or expiration dates set on child entries; tried removing channel, confirmed channel is correct. I've never used Playa to relate entries from the same channel to each other this way - is something else missing?

Comment: Try the field="" or field_id="" parameters. The details are in the docs... but field="" would contain the shortname of the Playa field. or field_id would be the field ID number.

Answer (score 3):

In your screenshot, “Obstetrics” is actually the *child*, not the parent, yet in your template code, you’re trying to pull in the children of Obstetrics. That {exp:playa:children} tag pair would only pull in entries if Obstetrics had its own Playa fields with their own related entries.

If you want to see all of the entries that are relating the Obstetrics entry via their own Playa fields, you need to use {exp:playa:parents}, not {exp:playa:children}.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I decided to move this to Structure because the client needs a more hierarchical setup.